Building Hmmer with OpenMPI
I'm trying to build Hmmer with OpenMPI support. However, I run into the issue:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_p7_oprofile_MPIRecv", referenced from:
      _main in jackhmmer.o
  "_p7_oprofile_MPISend", referenced from:
      _main in jackhmmer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [jackhmmer] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

I expect this to result from MPISend and MPIRecv not being successfully built with profiling. However, I'm not sure.
My install script for OMPI is:
install_openmpi() {
  cd ${PROJ_DIR}/deps/openmpi-5.0.5 || exit
  ./configure --prefix=${PROJ_DIR}/local --enable-mpi-profile
  make -j "$NPROC"
  make install
  cd ${PROJ_DIR}
}
install_openmpi

My install script for Hmmer is:
install_hmmer() {
  cd ${PROJ_DIR}/deps/hmmer-3.4 || exit
  ./configure --prefix=${PROJ_DIR}/local \
              --enable-threads \
              --enable-mpi
  make -j "$NPROC"
  make install
  cd ${PROJ_DIR}
}
install_hmmer

Additional information that may be relevant:
I find that p7_oprofile_MPISend(P7_OPROFILE *om, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, char **buf, int *nalloc) is defined in: deps/hmmer-3.4/src/impl_vmx/mpi.c. It is declared in deps/hmmer-3.4/src/hmmer.h and called in deps/hmmer-3.4/src/hmmer.c
How could I resolve this linker error?
